# Yahoo UI the popup implementation with YAHOO.widget.Dialog

Tags: yui

I used the Yahoo.widget.dialog to implement a popup window. Currently, it popups only on the page which is belongs. If I am working on the other (tab browser) pages. The popup window will be not seen.Could somebody supply some help for this ?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could either switch to [window.alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.alert) or use [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.open) to open a new pop-up window containing your content.

Neither one is something I'd personally want to experience, but those are your two options for opening a pop-up outside the page. Window.open will get caught by many pop-up blockers so you'll need to watch for that.